# Head Gesture To Tell Someone To Leave

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage, vocabulary

My question how can you describe it in a few words when you incline with your head that the person to leave without saying a word.

Thanks!

Comment: That's an upward head nod that signals it's time for you to go. But it's culturally based, and could mean other things. "You lookin' at me? You wanna piece of this?" There's a head nod called *cabaceo* in Argentine Tango salons that means "Shall we dance?"

Answer (score 2):

Related notions are:

*He waved me away* and *She nodded me away*

> Wave-away meaning
>
> (idiomatic) To reject or dismiss with a hand gesture
>
> [Your dictionary](https://www.yourdictionary.com/wave-away)

> Nod = If you nod, you bend your head once, as a way of saying hello or goodbye
>
> [Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/nod)

Hence **nod away** is to indicate goodbye and *nod in* is to invite in.

Google ngram has statistics for *nod them away* and shows examples such as

> Any time someone approached, Ophelia groaned, and Colin nodded them away.
>
> [Chasing the Heiress](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Chasing_the_Heiress/6oOCCgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22nodded+them+away%22&pg=PT324&printsec=frontcover)

Answer (score 1):

I might say **motion** (with the head).

> Direct or command (someone) with a movement of the hand or head.
> ‘he motioned Dennis to a plush chair’

https://www.lexico.com/definition/motion